# Pentaho Demo Graphs or Charts

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio

Recently had a project in JBoss but want to move to Pentaho (JBoss kept crashing). JBoss was good because it showed you sample data and various types of results when you installed it. When I installed Pentaho, it is like a clean slate and I do not see a demo feature that I can install and see how data is displayed.

Is there a link that anyone can point me to in order to look at sample data being generated into charts or graphs in Pentaho? I already have the common plugins installed - CDE, CDA, CDF, and CGG.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are samples in the /public/Steel Wheels folder.

If you install the CE version, you'll also get a lot of samples in /public/Plugin Samples.

Log in to PUC as admin and go to the explore files perspective. You should see them there.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple CDE tutorial I wrote. It uses screen shots from version 5.x but you could also use it for version 6.0 (they are similar).  Nothing fancy though: http://holowczak.com/getting-started-with-pentaho-community-edition-dashboard-editor-cde/